# C# Console App doesnt write to file when called by command line but does otherwise

Tags: c#, logging, console

I have a small console app that takes parameters. Througout i use a method to throw some info into a file as a log. Very simple:

```
        static void Log(string str)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("log.txt", true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(str);
            }
        }
```

However, when this program is run by command line invocation, the program runs but the log file isnt amended.

If the app is run by launching via explorer or debugging in visual studio the logging works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably a permissions issue.

Comment: Did you run as admin?

Comment: It probably is writing the file, but to the wrong folder. What happens if you use an absolute path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new StreamWriter("log.txt", true)` writes to the current working directory, which could be anywhere at all, including network shares or places you do not have write access to. Always specify the full path to any files. If you want to write to a file you need to make sure you write to a place you have access to. Do not just run your app as Administrator, that opens all kinds of security holes.

You probably want something like:

```
var p = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "myAppName");
if (!Directory.Exists(p)) Directory.CreateDirectory(p);
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(p, "log.txt"), true)
{
    sw.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Comment: I suppose I should have thought of that just to rule out for troubleshooting. But i dont see how 'c:\app\bin\debug\log.txt' doesnt have an issue where as the app running from the debug dir cant write to 'log.txt'.

Comment: But that has sorted it, thankyou for the explanation and code example, i really do need to use path.combine instead of an explicit string.

Thanks again - marked as answer for the verbose reply and code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the full write path like: `C:\Users\user\Documents\log.txt`